# how to remember results of a views query in rules

Tags: rules, views, cookies

I have a site with an [eva](http://www.drupal.org/project/eva) view that is embedded into a view page that is directly accessible, running the query for the first time. To that I have added [rules_views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules), I want to e-mail out certain fields values of the view when the user requests it using a flag. (as the trigger) But I want to e-mail the field values out after the query is first run, with the original values. I want to preserve the state.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to add hyperlinks to the modules you're using. and explain what you mean by "**out**" as in "e-mail out".

Comment: You did add the hyperlinks (merci!), but not the "***e-mail out***". 2nd try?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/qLEh67GJ it wouldn't let me add as many links as I needed to, so I hacked around it.

Comment: With your limited rep, I see your challenge to post "all" those links. Let me know if you want me to replace the entire content of your question here with a copy-paste of that pastbin-link in your prior comment, ok?

Comment: That would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible alternative to make this work (instead of using [Views Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_rules)), you may want to give it a try to *process the results of a [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) enabled view via [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)*, whereas your rule performs 2 Rules Actions:

- Load the VBO list that you want to be processed.
- Add a loop to perform a Rules Action, for each row contained in your Views results.

For more details, have a look at the tutorial "[How to process the results of a VBO enabled view via Rules?](http://drupal.placeto.be/question/90)".

To actually trigger such Rules Action, you should be able to use a Rules Event like "*... when the user requests it using a flag.*" (as in your question).

Comment: That is sort of what the Views Send module does, right? (I have been reading docs a lot.)

Comment: "for each row contained in your Views results." is there a way to make it only run the action if it's not already been run? There have been many questions here on stack exchange about things running multiple times.

Comment: Reading this after I have had some time to think, I would still need views periodic execution, right? my understanding of vbo (which is limited) is that it has to be called by something.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to accept your answer, but I did want to say thank you. It took me a while to get the hang of VBO... it requires both a views operations field and a "send e-mail" field. some more futzing with operations, and with other misc. things about my server configuration that I'm hoping will not rear itself. Thank you.